# For FancyBox jquery - how can I have a caption (below) and title (above) for each image

Tags: fancybox

I'm using FancyBox jquery for a slideshow. It's easy to have a title underneath each large image. My client also wants to have a title above the image. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!
Louis Libert

Comment: Here's the code on the button that opens the FancyBox:

<a id="fancybox-manual-c" href="javascript:;"><img class="images" src="/fancyapps/demo/1_thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a>

Comment: Here's the code in the <head> $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
    $.fancybox.open([
     {
      href : '/fancyapps/demo/1.jpg',
      title : 'Murray, Barry, Lenny. 1953.',
      caption : 'Chapter One'
     }, {
      href : '/fancyapps/demo/2.jpg',
      title : 'Me clowning for the family portrait at my brother Murray’s bar mitzvah. 1951.'
     }

Comment: Next time you can ask your friend Google ;)